# How do you set the Java and Tomcat version using Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli

I can successfully set the Java and Tomcat version for Azure web sites using the portal. For the CI/CD purposes, I need to be able to set it from the command line using Azure CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Azure CLI 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli) to set it.

```
az webapp config set --name
                     --resource-group
                     [--always-on {false, true}]
                     [--auto-heal-enabled {false, true}]
                     [--java-container]
                     [--java-container-version]
                     [--java-version]
                     [--linux-fx-version]
                     [--net-framework-version]
                     [--php-version]
                     [--python-version]
                     [--remote-debugging-enabled {false, true}]
                     [--slot]
                     [--startup-file]
                     [--use-32bit-worker-process {false, true}]
                     [--web-sockets-enabled {false, true}]
```

You could use `az webapp config set -h` to get help. You also could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config#set).

```
--java-container
The java container, e.g., Tomcat, Jetty.
--java-container-version
The version of the java container, e.g., '8.0.23' for Tomcat.
--java-version
The version used to run your web app if using Java, e.g., '1.7' for Java 7, '1.8' for Java 8.
```